# Crediting a typeface in a finished work

Tags: print-design, legal, typefaces

Hey does anyone know how you are supposed to credit (if you are supposed to) the typefaces you have used in a printed work (case in point - design exhibition catalogue for my BA)

I've been using elephant italics and a few free fonts :)

Comment: exactly what you asking ???? :O

Comment: Im asking how to give the type designers credit for fonts of theirs that I use in the book I'm going to print :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically/traditionally it's called the colophon:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colophon_%28publishing%29

From the article:

> […]
>
> With the development of the private press movement from around 1890, colophons became conventional in private press books, and often included a good deal of additional information on the book, including statements of limitation, data on paper, ink, type and binding, and other technical details. Some such books include a separate 'Note about the type', which will identify the names of the primary typefaces used, provide a brief description of the type's history and a brief statement about its most identifiable physical characteristics.
>
> Some commercial publishers took up the use of colophons, and began to include similar details in their books, either at the end of the text (the traditional position) or on the verso of the title-leaf. […]

Personally, I think it's a nice thing to do.

Comment: There's one at the end of each of the Harry Potter books (at least my hardcover copies), which includes the information that they are set in the beautiful Adobe Garamond.

Comment: See also an [example colophon](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-1264) (which was also mentioned in the wiki article).

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually *have to* credit typefaces in a finished work.

When you license a font, you are licensing that font file as if it is software, *not* the letter forms the software generates or the finished work generated by that software, as those are unprotected.  So there is no real requirement to acknowledge the font author or font in the finished work, at least with any common font license.

The exception is when you are distributing the work in digital form and the font file, or data derived from the font file, needs to be distributed along with the work in order for the recipient to see it with the intended font.  This is the case with web fonts, where a special license to distribute the font on the web needs to be obtained.  In this case you are actually distributing the font file and must read and obey the font license.

As for what you should do if you'd like to *voluntarily* acknowledge the typeface, font or font author, these as said might want to be placed into a "Colophon" section as described in DA01's answer.  In a book this is usually part of the front matter, overleaf from the title page (on the back of the same sheet, on the left) but before the table of contents.